# How to use TempDir in Extensions

Tags: junit, junit5

I'm playing around with JUnit 5.4.0 which supports the built-in @TempDir.

I'm trying to write an extension that resets the tempdir before each test by copying some template files.

However, the temporary directory seems to be uninitialised. The @TempDir tag seems to not have run. I'm not sure if I'm doing this wrong, but please let me know how I can fix this.

This problem only happens in extensions. It doesn't happen if I put everything in MainTest.java, but the whole purpose is for reusability - I want to reuse this tempdir that can reset itself with contents.

DirectoryResetExtension.java

```java
public class DirectoryResetExtension implements BeforeEachCallback {

    private Path TEST_DATA_FOLDER;

    @TempDir
    public Path tempDir;

    public static DirectoryResetExtension initializeWith(Path folder) {
        return new DirectoryResetExtension(folder);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeEach(ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(tempDir); // Gives null!
    }
}
```

MainTest.java

```java
public class MainTest {
    @RegisterExtension
    public static DirectoryResetExtension tempDir = DirectoryResetExtension.initializeWith(TEST_DATA_FOLDER);

    @Test
    public void easyTest() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Expected: tempDir is not null. System.out.println(tempDir) in DirectoryResetExtension prints a valid path.

Actual: tempDir is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered you on [Gitter](https://gitter.im/junit-team/junit5?at=5c62ccad253c2b5ea3fcf9d3). So I'll just copy-n-paste that here.

`@TempDir` is not supported in extensions. It is only supported in test classes.

In any case, there should not be a need to reset a temp directory.

The temp directory gets deleted after the current "scope". The scope depends on where you declare `@TempDir`.

If you want to copy things into the temp directory, you would typically do that in a `@BeforeAll` or `@BeforeEach` method in the test class.

If you actually need access to the JUnit-managed temp directory within an extension, you could [open a GitHub issue](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/new/choose) to discuss the possibilities.